# Adding url rewrites directly into database

Tags: magento2, nginx

Ive just added around 100 url rewrites directly into the url_rewrites db table but Magento doesn't use them, Ive reindexed and cleared the cache but really don't know what to do next - what am i missing ?

Comment: Did you mention respective entity_type and entity_id proper into DB? tried 2-3 first if you success thereafter that add other. entity_type is really mattered. after that just run **php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: The entity_type is custom so theres no associated entity id :( is there any other place that is used other than url_rewrites - the entries dont even show in the grid in the admin area

Comment: I actually just ran another index and it seems to have worked - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, Please do remove those from database and do install below extension... so it will do provide an to generate new URL, generate new and keep OLD etc.

Please do review below extension from github for more details...
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

**Problem solved? Please give 'Kudos' and accept 'Answer as Solution'**